# Xidel get json from HTML tag attribute

Tags: xidel

I am trying to extract an image URL from a div, where the link to the file is stored as a json object in data-settings attribute:

```
<div class="c-offerBox_galleryItem">
    <div data-component="magnifier" data-component-on="@load" data-settings="{
                image: '/media/cache/gallery/rc/p2vgiqwd/images/42/42542/KRHE7Z29X19.jpg',
                ratio: 1.5,
                outside: 0
            }"></div>
</div>
```

Currently I can access data-settings with:

```
xidel "https://example.com" -e "//div[@class='c-offerBox_galleryItem']/div/@data-setting
```

The output is the json object. How can I access the image object?

I thought something like:

```
xidel "https://example.com" -e "//div[@class='c-offerBox_galleryItem']/div/@data-setting/$json/image
```

would work, but not.

Comment: Judging by your use of quotes I guess you're a Windows user. I would add the `cmd`-tag in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only use the global default variable `$json` when "https://example.com" itself returns a JSON.
To parse a string as JSON use [`parse-json()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#fn-parse-json). And in this case you'll need the option "liberal" as well.

```
xidel -s "https://example.com" -e "//div[@class='c-offerBox_galleryItem']/div/parse-json(@data-settings,{'liberal':true()})"
```

For Xidel 0.9.8 use [`json()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#pxp-json) (deprecated for newer builds).

```
xidel -s "https://example.com" -e "//div[@class='c-offerBox_galleryItem']/div/json(@data-settings)"
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting: err:XPST0017: unknown function: parse-json #1

Comment: @Adrian Then the binary you're using is too old.

Comment: I think this is the latest. $ xidel --version
Xidel 0.9.8
(20180421.6162.1f357eaaf5f3)

http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html

Comment: @Adrian No, xidel-0.9.9.20211123.8232.023d1f1f656e is the latest. http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html: _"[Development snapshots](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/) are provided in a special download folder occasionally."_

Comment: OMG this was so hard to find, but now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Adrian Long time ago since I last used Xidel 0.9.8. See updated answer.